# How to use two different languages for making one program?

Tags: java, c++, c

I have heard sometimes that the front end of a program was written in language A and the back end in language B. Can i do it for desktop programs I make too? Like do the graphics with Java and the back end with C or C++. How do i do it?

PS. Sorry if its a newbie question because I am one.

**edit 1**
Because i am told that my question is too broad, here is what I exactly want. How can I link mt action listener in java with a C program? For example, if i have a button "next hundred primes" i want the button to be made in Java and primes calculated using C.

Comment: What you're really asking is how can two different processes communicate. Start researching that and you'll inevitably find your answer.

Comment: @Kon: The question is not specifically asking for distinct processes. This could very well be implemented in a single process (by hosting a JRE and/or calling into native code with JNI).

Comment: I like the JRE hosted in a C++ process solution variation, @IInspectable!

Comment: Although you *can* mix Java and C using JNI, if would be best to stick with languages using the same technology: [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) (Java, Scala, Clojure, Groovy, ...), [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages) (C#, VB.NET, ...), or machine code (C, C++, Delphi, ...). Mixing technologies complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one Java process with [JNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), for example. Java effectively calls C++ as a library.

This can also be done multi-process by having Java process create a C++ process then capture its output as, for example, C++ process exit code, standard output or created file.

A third way to do this would be to have a long-running C++ process listen on a TCP socket then have the Java program communicate with its C++ back-end over the network, either on the same machine or across an intranet.

Other methods also surely exist. These are just a few I know off the top of my head. :)

Comment: Yes. Also, binding assembler code into C was done a lot in the earlier days. And with Java, you can control data to and from a captured/started application with the standard in/out/error streams. On the other hand, why would you wanna do that? Why not keep it simple?

Comment: @JayC667, GUI atop console app(s) is a cheap way to add a GUI to an app that has or needs a console interface. Chances are `git gui`, for example, is or was a Tk interface atop the Git console application(s). Earlier back [XBoard] has a similar GUI atop console app with standard communication protocol architecture.